# Alternatives to a lot of if statements

Tags: javascript

I am writing code that will be used to create citations for a website, and the problem I am currently working on is what to do if the citation data is missing information, such as missing the author or title. So, what I have currently implemented is a bunch of if statements to check if the particular citation is missing any info, essentially it looks like:

```
if (citationdata.authors) {
    citation += citationdata.authors
}
else {
    citation += "Unknown author. "
}
```

and so on for any other check I need to make for that particular citation type, which ends up being about 5-6 separate if statements until the full citation is built up.

I'm relatively new to using javascript, so, my question is whether or not this would be considered bad practice, and if so what are any alternatives that I could use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something this simple can be reduced to:

```
citation += citationdata.authors || "Unknown author. ";
```

The [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) will convert whatever is on the left to a Boolean value, and if it is a '*truthy*' value, it will return the left side of the expression, otherwise it will evaluate and return the right side of the expression.

'*Falsey*' values include:

- The Boolean value `false`
- The empty string
- The number `0`
- `NaN`
- `null`
- `undefined`

All other values are '*truthy*'.

Comment: wow I have never seen this, does this work like ternary operator?

Comment: @meda Yes, the expression `x || y` in JS is equivalent to `x ? x : y`.

Comment: This often works, but can give some problems if you'd actually like to print out the number 0 (as intimated at in the description of 'Falsey' values).

Comment: @ColinDeClue correct, but the same problem exists OP's original code. To be more explicit, use `('authors' in citationdata) ? citationdata.authors : "Unknown author. "`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Follow up question, is there any benefit to this kind of shorthand other than cutting down on code length/readability?

Comment: @user95420 It's perfectly equivalent to your original code, so there's no other benefit. However, if you need to accept '*falsey*' values like an empty string (which would be rejected by your original code and mine), see my previous comment to Colin.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract your conditional checking out into a method that you would call for each property you want to have checked. Something like...

```
function getCitationData(data, propName, noDataMesage) {
    if(data[propName]) {
        return data[propName];
    }
    return noDataMessage;
}


citation += getCitationData(citationdata, "authors", "Unknown author. ");
```

Comment: Even this can be simplified to `function getCitationData(data, propName, noDataMesage) { return data[propName] || noDataMessage; }`

Comment: Very true. Although we don't truly know what data type is being returned from data[propName] so for clarity I went with the extended version...